# Failing to clip Corine land cover to a 3km buffer zone

Tags: qgis, shapefile, clip

I am trying to clip a Corine land cover shapefile to a 3km buffer zone so I can get the land use types + hectare amounts of that 3km radius.
Firstly, it fails to clip the pastures attribute to the buffer (invalid geometry).
And then other layers which do clip but fall both in and outside the 3km radius show the entire hectare amount for that land use, in and outside the buffer and not just the area that has been clipped.

I was wondering is it possible to do what I am asking or am I doing something wrong?
The crs is the same for both the map and corine shape file.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: After clipping to your 3 km buffer, you need to recalculate the feature areas. This is not done automatically. Search in the QGIS documentation on calculating areas: i.e. [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#editing-attribute-values)

Answer (score 0):

What I do in these cases is

1. "Select" all features within a buffer zone that extends beyond the actual buffer zone that I need.
2. "Export" all those selected features to a new shapefile
3. "Correct geometries" of that new layer
4. "Cut" the corrected layer to the buffer zone you actually want (3 km, as I understand)
5. Using the field calculator, create a new field and "calculate" the area of the newly created polygons.